# “Bad binary signature” in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, 64-bit, aspnet-merge

I'm experiencing the same issue reported here: ["Bad binary signature" in ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101529/bad-binary-signature-in-asp-net-mvc-application)

The ASP.Net MVC site works fine on the local machine, but when deployed using a combination of aspnet_compiler, aspnet_merge, and msdeploy, loading any page will fail with the following error:

> System.BadImageFormatException
>   Bad binary signature. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131192)

The accepted solution in the linked question suggests that the issue is caused by using the wrong version of aspnet_merge, and I have verified that removing the aspnet_merge step from the deployment solves the issue.

My problem is that using the correct aspnet_merge version doesn't appear to resolve the issue.

The web application is targeting .Net 4.0 64-bit.
The aspnet_merge path used is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\aspnet_merge.exe"

**[EDIT]**

Local dev is:

- VS2010 SP1
- Cassini
- x64
- VS11 Beta and .Net 4.5 are installed

Build paths are:

- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
- C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\

Comment: Works find on local machine(Cassini, IIS 7.5, IIS Express?) Is your local IIS machine 64 bit? Do you have .Net 4.5 installed on your dev machine?

Comment: I've added extra detail in the problem description

Answer (score 2):

I've also experienced a similar issue using a Web Deployment Project to pre-compile an ASP.NET Web Site Project in VS2010 (.NET 4.0).

Everything worked fine until I installed VS2012 (which installs .NET 4.5 - I presume that is related) which started giving me:

`System.BadImageFormatException: Bad binary signature. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131192)`

After some debugging and isolated test cases I tracked the issue down to a lambda being passed between the .NET 4.0 web site and another .NET 3.5 project.

The method defined in the 3.5 project had a signature like this:

```
public IEnumberable<T> ExecuteAsEnumerable(Func<IDataReader, T> func)
{
  //..
}
```

which was being used in the 4.0 website in a property getter resulting in the error when merged via aspnet_merge:

```
public IList<MyObject> MyListOfItems
{
  get
  { 
    return _myListOfItems ?? (_myListOfItems = new SomeQueryBuilder()
      //.build statement
      .ExecuteAsEnumerable(reader => new MyObject(reader))
      .ToArray());
  }
}
```

In my test case I recreated `ExecuteAsEnumerable` as an different named extension method inside the 4.0 web site, pre-compiled, and it worked. After checking the "Target .NET Framework" of the project and realising it was 3.5 (I hadn't realised before), I switched everything to 4.0, and everything worked again.

Something obviously changed in the .NET 4.5 update (which was an in place upgrade over 4.0). In my case I could recompile the project in question - I'm not sure everyone would have that luxury (is that the right word?).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please email sample repro code for the issue you describe above on netfx45Compat@microsoft.com

Comment: @Anand: I've sent the email and included a sample project.

Comment: got repro. Will look at it tomorrow morning. Thanks for repro. Much appreciated.

Comment: We will consider fixing this in next product release.

Comment: @Anand i believe i have stumbled on this. please consider fixing this asap.

Comment: Didn't solve my problem directly, but points to an issue enumerables with helped me further.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exception as well. It wasn't a aspnet_merge version issue either, nor an issue with the target framework as far as I can tell. It is however on a older project recently updated to MVC 5.

I had this code in the Razor view:

```
var companies = users.Select(u => u.Company).DistinctBy(c => c.Id)
                             .OrderBy(c => c.Id == CurrentUser.Company.Id ? 0 : 1)
                             .ThenBy(c => c.Name);
```

It uses Linq and `DistinctBy` for the MoreLinq library. As this shouldn't be in a View anyway, I moved it to the controller and the exception vanished.